# MS Access 2016 VBA Error 2424 the expression you entered has a field, control, or property name that Microsoft Access cannot find

Tags: vba, ms-access

(the control is a checkbox control)
Here are the variations of code that I have tried:
(the error occurs on this line of code at the point where it references the control)

```
If Me.ControlName = True Then
If Me.ControlName.Value = True Then
If forms("form_name").form.controls("ControlName").value = True then
If forms("form_name").form.controls("ControlName") = True then
if forms!form_name!ControlName.value = True then
```

The control exists on the form and is connected to a field of a different name.
The control name and field name are not used anywhere else in this database and are not reserved words.  (The control name is "CheckHot" and field is "Hot", and the form is a unique non-reserved name and the form name is not used for any other object or purpose in this database).

The control is definitely on the form where the code is located.

All other references to controls on this form work fine.

I tried file -> compact and repair
I also tried creating a new blank database and importing all objects

I am getting ready to delete the control and re-add it to the form now... but if anyone has any other ideas please let me know -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer... turns out the field (control source) of the control was temporarily not part of the forms record source when this code was running...

thanks!

Comment: Yes. 
I have linked tables of Access to tables of SQL Serve. Whenever i change SQL Server tables but don't relink them on Access, I get this error when opening the corresponding bounded forms.